# How to get the original file name over UDP

Tags: java, udp

guys. I have a question on how to receive a file over UDP connection and name it with the original name specified by the sender. For example, if the sender sends a file named big.mp4. My receiver program will receive the file and directly name it big.mp4 in the current directory without taking in any input regarding the file name. I'm currently using the java class datagramsocket and datagrampacket, but every time i need to create a new file, get the data from the datapacket and then write into the file that I created(of course, I have to name it with a random name). Any idea on how to solve this? Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you want the complete filename, send the complete filename. Although what use a filename relative to one system is on another system remains a mystery.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the receiver to write the same file name, you should send the file name in the message.

Note: UDP is a lossy protocol. There is no guarantee that packets will be received at all, in order, or without fragmentation if > 532 bytes.